# Is it possible to build n-depth trees representations with Normalizr?

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I'm feeling like I am perhaps fighting Normalizr too much and have perhaps misunderstood what I can and can't use it for. I want to take a flat data structure and build a nested tree from references contained in the flat data.

For instance I want to take as an input:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1077,
    "title": "Hello world",
    "children": [{
      "id": 3076
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3076,
    "title": "Hello foo",
    "children": [{
      "id": 3077
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3077,
    "title": "Hello bar",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3078,
    "title": "Goodbye world",
    "children": [],
  }
];
```

And output a nested tree representation:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1077,
    "title": "Hello world",
    "children": [{
       "id": 3076,
       "title": "Hello foo",
        "children": [{
          "id": 3077,
          "title": "Hello bar",
          "children": []
        }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 3078,
    "title": "Goodbye world",
    "children": [],
  }
];
```

I then want to be able to normalize the tree back to the flat structure before sending back to the server. I can think of a number of ways of doing this outside of Normalizr, however I was hoping I could maybe bend Normalizr to my will and learn something along the way.

Comment: did you figure out a way to do this? I have some Rails data that is using ancestry and would like to use either Redux or Vuex with it.

Comment: I did not. I've come to the conclusion that this isn't the way to use Normalizr. I resolved to getting the backend to output the tree structured data I need and not being able to flatten it in the Store. This is largely ok because I am only modelling self referential data, so there are no cases where I change tree data and it affects another model indirectly (related nested models is where Normalizr comes in handy).

You can still shove it all in Redux with or without Normalizr anyways.